# Creating a new view with to subviews, get graphics context destroys original view?

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, uiview

I hope that title makes some sense.

I have UIView (created in IB) where I add stuff (images). Then, I have a UILabel with some text. Now, I want to make a UIImage out of that, which I do like this:

```
UIView *comp = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.previewView.frame];
    [comp addSubview:self.previewView];
    [comp addSubview:self.lblCaption];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(comp.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
    [comp.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

self.previewView and self.lblCaption are both created in IB. previewView is just a screen-filling view.

The code-block is executed in an IBAction after a button-tap.

Which works wonderful, I get the image as expected and can process it further.

But after that, the contents of «self.previewView» are gone? When I do an NSLog, everything seems to be there, but it's not visible on screen anymore.

Does anyone have an idea what's going on here?

[Edit]

As the answer below states, the view was added to self.view before, so it was removed when I added it to the comp. The solution is pretty easy, actually, I changed the code to the following: (created a function that returns a UIImage. That's a bit cleaner than doing it in code....

```
-(UIImage *)imageFromView:(UIView *)theView andLabel:(UILabel *)theLabel{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(comp.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
    [theView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    [theLabel.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return viewImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just guessing assuming possible situations...

Assuming you were showing `self.previewView` on some other view, say `self.view`.

When you added `self.previewView` to `comp`, it may have been removed from `self.view`. (Considering that UIView.superview is only single instance, I am thinking this is very likely).

If this is the case, re-adding `self.previewView` to `self.view` after obtaining image would solve the problem.

Comment: That was it, exactly. Which is logic since the self.previewView only exists once. So now I added the solution in my post.

Thanks again